# Deleting sheet in excel using python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

```
m1 = pd.ExcelFile('C:\\Users\\a\\Desktop\\1.xlsx')
df1 = pd.read_excel(m1, sheet_name='Raw Data')
df1.head()

m2 = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\a\\Desktop\\stbd.xlsx')
m2.head()

# drop all values in m1
df1 = df1.drop(labels=range(0 , df1.shape[0]) , axis=0)
df1.shape
```

I wanted to delete data in a sheet of excel workbook and overwrite the same sheet with new data and to refresh the pivot table in next sheet with new data. But once I use this code part and run it, all other sheets(sheets which has pivot tables) in the workbook is deleted. Can someone support me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to read all the sheets of the excel file and then save them all including the changed one

```
m1 = pd.ExcelFile('C:\\Users\\a\\Desktop\\1.xlsx')
df1 = pd.read_excel(m1, sheet_name=list(m1.sheet_names))

#change the specific sheet
df1["sheet to change"] = 'house' #something to change

writer = pd.ExcelWriter("output_excel_file.xlsx", engine = 'xlsxwriter')

for sheet in m1.sheet_names:
    df1[sheet].to_excel(writer,index=False, sheet_name=sheet)

writer.save()
```

Something like that.

Comment: Thankyou so much. I will try this. Do you have any method create pivot using python?

Comment: @user19875567 Do you want to change specific rows of the table? u can use apply method or np.vectorize for custom loops.